# I can't login on wordpress admin page

Tags: wordpress

I can't login on wordpress admin page.it show "/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fcn.radiomandarin.fr%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"

Comment: The url seems right. Can you still login onto the database?

Comment: Yes I can login onto the database

Answer (score 1):

You are able to reset your password via the database.
I presume you use phpMyAdmin

follow the this tutorial:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Use the steps given in the chapter 'Through phpMyAdmin'

Comment: i can login on to the phpMyAdmin. I just can't login onto the wp-admin the admin page.

Comment: Yes we get that, you get into phpMyAdmin and change the password for your user account.

Comment: a I got it let me try

Comment: I change my user password , but i still can't login wp-admin page.